# Hover en Imagen con Boostrap

Tags: html, css, hover

He probado de hacer un hover sencillo de cambio de tamaño con la imagen pero no me acaba de salir, dejo codigo CSS y HTML:

```css
.baseNumeros {
    z-index:4;
}

.RNumeros {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform .2s;
}

.RNumeros:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5); 
}

.PNumeros {
    color:black;
}

.BarraNumeros {
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border:black 2px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px black;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container-fluid base">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm-4 baseNumeros" >
                    <img class="RNumeros" src="~/css/imatges/ReinoNumeros.png">
                    <div class="progress BarraNumeros center-block">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active PNumeros" 
                            role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
                            style="width:40%">
                            40%
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Reino 2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">Reino final</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yo no le veo nada mal, lo probé y funciona, si hace el scale de la imagen, será que tienes un CSS aparte que está interviniendo?

Comment: ¿Con qué versión de navegador pruebas? ten en cuenta que según [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) podría ser un problema de la versión/navegador usado, por ejemplo, IE9 no lo soporta.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Google Chrome. Hay un apartado que se puede forzar el hover des del inspeccionar elemento y si que va, pero al ponerme encima no hace el efecto.

Answer (score 0):

Al tener una animacion de fondo (CSS) habia puesto prioridades de capas con "**index-z**" y habia una capa que estaba por delante de la imagen, solo he tenido que subir la prioridad poniendo "**index-z: 1**" y ya me cogia el hover.